# Adding to integer value with update or insert statement

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to create a SQL statement in Firebird 2.5 in order to update an integer quantity by adding to it if the record exists or simply insert a new row. I can't seem to find a real answer to my specific question about adding to a certain quantity if it already exists.

The SQL I could think of is the following :

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
VALUES('12345678/90', 'TOP', 20)
MATCHING(Number, Location);
```

So if there is a matching record I would like to add a certain amount to the actual 20 quantity.

Like I would do with an `UPDATE` statement  :

```
UPDATE Pencils SET Quantity = Quantity + 20 WHERE Number = '12345678/90'
```

Is it possible to achieve such result with the `UPDATE OR INSERT` statement or is there another way?
.
.

**EDIT :**
Solution for a query used with parameters with IBExpert / Delphi

```
MERGE INTO Pencils AS Dest
USING (SELECT CAST(:myNumb as varchar(30))  AS Number,
              CAST(:myLoca as varchar(10))  AS Location,
              CAST(:myQuan as integer)  AS Quantity
        FROM RDB$DATABASE) Src
    ON (Dest.Number = Src.Number AND Dest.Location = Src.Location)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET Dest.Quantity = Dest.Quantity + Src.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (Number, Location, Quantity) VALUES (Src.Number, Src.Location, Src.Quantity);
```

Comment: And for total freaks there is yet another ancient way to do it, which predates MERGE, U-O-I and even Firebird itself. It takes creating **updatable view** where U/I/D operations are implemented by PSQL code in `triggers`, and then `Before Insert` trigger would check if there is or is no row in the underlying table already. But this would be such a Rube Goldberg Machine... Lovely and charming like NormalizeRect in Delphi XE2 :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Firebird's [MERGE](https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-merge.html) for complex UPSERTs:

```
MERGE INTO Pencils AS Dest
USING (SELECT '12345678/90' AS Number,
              'TOP'         AS Location,
              20            As Quantity
         FROM RDB$DATABASE) Src
   ON (Dest.Number = Src.Number AND Dest.Location = Src.Location)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET Dest.Quantity = Dest.Quantity + 10
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (Number, Location, Quantity) VALUES (Src.Number, Src.Location, Src.Quantity);
```

The only complexity here is your dynamically computed `Quantity` on UPDATE.  If you were simply overwriting an existing record with static values, you could use [UPDATE OR INSERT](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-update-or-insert.html) more succinctly.

**Example:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM Pencils;

NUMBER               QUANTITY LOCATION         
================ ============ ================ 
123                         5 TOP              
123                        10 MID              

SQL> MERGE INTO Pencils AS Dest
CON> USING (SELECT '123' AS Number, 'TOP' AS Location, 20 As Quantity
CON> FROM RDB$DATABASE) Src ON (Dest.Number = Src.Number AND Dest.Location = Src.Location)
CON> WHEN MATCHED THEN
CON>    UPDATE SET Dest.Quantity = Dest.Quantity + 10
CON> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
CON>    INSERT (Number, Location, Quantity) VALUES (Src.Number, Src.Location, Src.Quantity);

SQL> SELECT * FROM Pencils;

NUMBER               QUANTITY LOCATION         
================ ============ ================ 
123                        15 TOP              
123                        10 MID              

SQL> SELECT * FROM Pencils;

NUMBER               QUANTITY LOCATION         
================ ============ ================ 
123                         5 TOP              
123                        10 MID              

SQL> MERGE INTO Pencils AS Dest
CON> USING (SELECT '123' AS Number, 'TOP' AS Location, 20 As Quantity
CON> FROM RDB$DATABASE) Src ON (Dest.Number = Src.Number AND Dest.Location = Src.Location)
CON> WHEN MATCHED THEN
CON>    UPDATE SET Dest.Quantity = Dest.Quantity + 10
CON> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
CON>    INSERT (Number, Location, Quantity) VALUES (Src.Number, Src.Location, Src.Quantity);

SQL> SELECT * FROM Pencils;

NUMBER               QUANTITY LOCATION         
================ ============ ================ 
123                        15 TOP              
123                        10 MID              
123                        20 BOT
```

Comment: If I understand your statement right, If the record doesn't exist it will insert 20 as quantity but it should insert 10 (10 is a dnymic value I will get from Delphi program wich will be the quantity to insert)

Comment: @VirussInside Then you change the statement to use 10 instead of 20.

Comment: But I think Firebird doesn't allow the SELECT without FROM in the USING statement

Comment: Cant make it work properly in my DB, it updates the value multiplied by the matched records for example 3x the same Pencil but in 3 different locations (TOP, BOT, LEF)  will add +30 in the TOP instead of +10

Comment: @VirussInside make sample tables with data and queries on http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 - it should be some error in the `ON` closure most probably

Comment: @VirussInside, yes I neglected to include `FROM RDB$DATABASE`.  I picked 20 as the default because your example UPDATE OR INSERT did the same — that's easy to change.  See the examples; this works for me.

Comment: @pilcrow Oh of course it is 'FROM RDB$DATABASE' I was trying to make it work with 'FROM Pencil'... obviously it wasn't working as I expected. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: @pilcrow I forgot about one thing, is that I would like to use parameters for the values like ->    SELECT :myNumber AS Number,
                             :myLocation         AS Location,
                             :myQuantity         AS Quantity
              FROM RDB$DATABASE
Because I want to use the query in my Delphi program so I can replace these params with a dynmaic value I get from textefields.
But I get an error 'Data type unknown' in firebird.

Comment: @virussinside frankly it is a different question, and one probably answered million times. This is hen and egg problem when preparing queries, FB can not start preparing before knowing datatypes and finalizing binary buffer layout for output rowset, and it can not infer unknown datatypes before starting preparing. So you should hardcode parameters datatypes in before. `Select ? From RDB$DATABASE` would usually fail, but `Select cast( ? as integer) From RDB$DATABASE` would work. Kudos for hitting it. I was waiting in ambush wondering if you go lazy way without parameters at all.

Comment: Here is the DB<>[Fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=a17cde059a62028e1a0c646cd8a975c1)
The last attempt is what im trying to code in order to specifiy my parameters dynamically in my Delphi program.

Comment: 1) Firebird does not have named parameters, at all. It is Delphi's (in your case) specifics, added on top of standard SQL. C# does the same, though they AFAIR use `@name` instead of `:name` convention. 2) DB-Fiddle does not support parameters at all, it would require to introduce significantly more complex logic with different latched states of queries. So, there would be no data there on DBFiddle. But you can at least see there is no SQL errors either. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=ee6afc597e679819620f4e8c273f1787 @virussinside

Comment: Additionally, there is no such data type as `varchar` in Firebird! You have to specify length

Comment: @Arioch'The Last comment I think... Because I have a fully functional query exactly like I wanted it to work. As you said Firebird or Fiddle don't support parameters but my IBExpert SQL Editor does such as my Delphi program. And of course varchar needed to be varchar(30) in order to work. I updated the [Fiddle]https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=284bc001600f17cd6397ec090daabf90
even though it doesn't support it.

Comment: @VirussInside Firebird does support parameters but not named ones. DBFiddle does not support them at all. IBExpert is Delphi program written with DevRace FIB+ library (now defunct, but once most feature-packed of all IB/FB libs). You can use TraceAPI window in IBExpert to see how your queries are transformed before arriving to FB server. (though i prefer http://FBProfiler.sf.net for tracing, IBExpert's TraceAPI GUI is slick-looking but less functional actually)

Comment: BTW, equal problem with unknown output datatypes makes the difference between `INSERT INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
VALUES('12345678/90', 'TOP', 13) returning ? ` and `INSERT INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
VALUES('12345678/90', 'MID', 7) returning cast(? as float) `

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use update-or-insert.
But you would have to repeat your key values, which would make your query fragile (change only one of two values - and you got misbehaving query)

```
UPDATE OR INSERT 
   INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
VALUES( '12345678/90', 'TOP', 
  20 + coalesce(
        ( Select Quantity 
             From Pencils 
          where Number = '12345678/90' 
            and Location = 'TOP' )
       ,0 )
       )
MATCHING(Number, Location);
```

In Delphi most libraries would not support multiple SQL parameters with the same name, so you would probably have to actually make two parameters, similarly but distinctly named, for this approach to work.

So, all in all, `MERGE` would be better approach, safer. But for the sake of completeness, this should work too.

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table Pencils( Number varchar(20), Location varchar(10), Quantity int,
>    constraint pk_pens primary key (number, location) )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
> VALUES('12345678/90', 'TOP', 13)
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
> VALUES('12345678/90', 'MID', 7)
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from pencils
> ```
>
> ```
> NUMBER      | LOCATION | QUANTITY
> :---------- | :------- | -------:
> 12345678/90 | TOP      |       13
> 12345678/90 | MID      |        7
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE OR INSERT 
>    INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
> VALUES( '12345678/90', 'TOP', 
>   20 + coalesce(
>           (Select Quantity 
>              From Pencils 
>           where Number = '12345678/90' 
>             and Location = 'TOP')
>        ,0 )
>        )
> MATCHING(Number, Location);
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> UPDATE OR INSERT 
>    INTO Pencils(Number, Location, Quantity)
> VALUES( '12345678/90', 'BOTTOM', 
>   20 + coalesce(
>           (Select Quantity 
>              From Pencils 
>           where Number = '12345678/90' 
>             and Location = 'BOTTOM')
>        ,0 )
>        )
> MATCHING(Number, Location);
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from pencils
> ```
>
> ```
> NUMBER      | LOCATION | QUANTITY
> :---------- | :------- | -------:
> 12345678/90 | TOP      |       33
> 12345678/90 | MID      |        7
> 12345678/90 | BOTTOM   |       20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=32c5f4e5779c2090a211423d96ae084b)*

---

@pilcrow asks: For completeness, could you show the UPDATE OR INSERT where the newly INSERTed Quantity is *not* simply "zero + increment"?

Based on `NULL` semantics in expressions it would just take modifying the middle part of the query like that:

```
.........
VALUES( '12345678/90', 'TOP', 
  coalesce( 20 + -- increment when found
        ( Select Quantity 
             From Pencils 
          where Number = '12345678/90' 
            and Location = 'TOP' )
       ,  -15 /* new value when not found */ )
       )
.......
```

Comment: For completeness, could you show the UPDATE OR INSERT where the newly INSERTed Quantity is _not_ simply "zero + increment"?  Based on clarifying comments, I believe the OP does want a new record to default to "zero + increment", but the question as written says "20 for new records" and "Quantity += 10 for updated".  That'd be a different UP OR IN, and might be useful for someone, too.

Comment: @pilcrow Exactly, I have only one quantity for example 20 and I want a new record with this amount if number and location are not found or simply add these same 20 to an existing quantity.  
So it's   'zero + newQuantity' or 'oldQuantity += newQuantity'

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't think of COALESCE but you are right it will be pretty fragile to have different parameters for the same value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pilcrow done, but i am not at PC ATM, so did not actually try it. Might have minor syntax errors

Comment: @Arioch'The same question as my last comment on the answer, is it possible to replace the static values we put in the SELECT by replacing them with parameters like :myNumber, :myLocation

Comment: @VirussInside Already answered, and let's keep MERGE-related questions where they belong. In the U-O-I statement here above there is no parameter in output rowset, so that problem does not happen here. It would be confusing further readers to discuss that here.